# Azure Point-to-Site: Is it possible to read the Public certificate data from Key Vault instead of storing it as plain text in the Point-to-Site Config

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have configured the Point-to-Site in Azure as shown below

[image]

Is it possible to read the Public certificate data from Key Vault instead of storing it as plain text in the Point-to-Site configuration section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I generated public root certificate like below:

```json
$Policy = New-AzKeyVaultCertificatePolicy -SecretContentType "application/x-pkcs12" -SubjectName "CN=contoso.com" -IssuerName "Self" -ValidityInMonths 6 -ReuseKeyOnRenewal

Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "<your-unique-keyvault-name>" -Name "ExampleCertificate" -CertificatePolicy $Policy
```

[image]

Now, I tried to read the public certificate data from Key Vault i downloaded the certificate like below:

[image]

To copy the public certificate data, you have to open it via notepad and paste it in the Point-to-Site configuration like below:

[image]

[image]

> **Note that currently it is not possible to read the public certificate data from Key Vault in the Point-to-Site configuration section.**